# How to code a percent chance of an increase in a value

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a complete newcomer to coding, but I am working on a project that requires the use of Google Apps Script with Google Sheets. Basically, a part of the project involves a button that increases each number in a set of numbers by 1, but only a certain percentage of the time. The percent chance for each number is different. For example, imagine a set of 3 numbers. When the button is clicked, there is a 10% chance that the first number will increase, a 20% chance that the second will increase, and a 30% chance that the third will. Maybe all of them increase, maybe some, maybe none. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

Google Apps Script:

```
function one(value1) {
  var array1=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  value1+=array1[Math.floor(Math.random()*array1.length)];
  return value1;
}
function two(value2) {
  var array2=[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  value2+=array2[Math.floor(Math.random()*array2.length)];
  return value2;
}
function three(value3) {
  var array3=[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  value3+=array3[Math.floor(Math.random()*array3.length)];
  return value3
}
```

html:(one of these for each function)

```
<input type="button" value="one" onClick="one()" /><input type="text" id="one" />
```

JavaScript:(one of these for each function

```
  <script>
    function one() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(v){
        document.getElementById('one').value=v;
      })
      .one{document.getElementById('one').value}
    }
  </script>
```

You can put all of this into single a dialog or sidebar